# Convert VARCHAR data to DATE in MariaDB v. 10.1.xx

Tags: mysql, sql, date, type-conversion, mariadb

I have a table where the 'birth date' column is a VARCHAR data type, I need this column and try to convert it to DATE.
I found the function "STR_TO_DATE" in the MariaDB documentation that I tried.

For example: Table

```
===================
| ID | Birth_Date |
===================
| 1  | 10.02.1990 |
-------------------
| 2  | 2.5.1986   |
===================
```

I'm Trying:

```
UPDATE   Table
SET      Birth_Date = STR_TO_DATE(Birth_Date, '% d/ %m /% Y');
```

But the SQL server returns:

> \ Incorrect datetime value: '10.02.1990' for function str_to_date.

Is there a simpler procedure in MariaDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in your table use `.` as a delimiter. You should use it in the format string too:

```
STR_TO_DATE(Birth_Date, '%d.%m.%Y');
```

Comment: Great. I didn't try that. I thought the date format on STR_TO_DATE could be any. But the format must match the target format. Have nice Christmas time.  @ Mureinik